# Swift implicit type conversion between C typedefs

Tags: swift

I need to use a third party C library whose source I cannot modify and which makes heavy use of implicit type casting and typedefs to set values for its structs. They are all ints underneath and this is the preferred way of interacting with this library. I've previously used it in Objective C code without issue so now I am mostly porting some of my old code, but it feels like I am constantly hitting a brick wall with Swift.

---

**tl;dr: how can I assign a different typedef value to a C struct member in Swift while automatically handling the type conversions (all typedefs are ints underneath)?**

---

For example, consider the following definitions:

```
struct library_struct {
    int member;
};        

typedef enum library_consts {
    LIBRARY_DEFINED_VALUE = 0
} library_consts;
```

In C or Objective C it would be absolutely acceptable to perform the following:

```
library_struct a;
a.member = LIBRARY_DEFINED_VALUE
```

However, attempting to do the same thing in Swift

```
var a: library_struct = library_struct()
a.member = LIBRARY_DEFINED_VALUE
```

results in an error: 
`Cannot assign a value of type 'library_consts' to a  value of type 'Int32'`

I tried several approaches:

1. Cast using `Int32()`. This leads to a `Cannot find an initializer for type 'Int32' that accepts and argument list of type (library_consts)` error.
2. Use `LIBRARY_DEFINED_VALUE.rawValue`. This won't work, because rawValue will return an UInt32, so I'm going to get the following error: `Cannot assign a value of type 'UInt32' to a value of type 'Int32'`
3. The only alternative is to cast again the value returned by `rawValue` to an `Int32` like this: `Int32(LIBRARY_DEFINED_VALUE.rawValue)`

This works, but it feels wrong to make a double cast and it doesn't solve more complicated situations such as assigning a value of a different type (but still an int underneath) to a struct member such as the following:

```
enum library_consts
{
    LIB_FALSE=0,
    LIB_TRUE=1
};

typedef int lib_bool_t;

typedef struct another_struct {
    lib_bool_t aFlag;
}

var b: another_struct = another_struct()
a.aFlag = LIB_FALSE
```

This will error out with "Cannot assign a value of type 'library_consts' to a  value of type 'lib_bool_t'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no easier solution if you cannot change the
C interface. Using the "Generated Interface" view in Xcode 7 you can
see that

```
enum library_consts
{
    LIB_FALSE=0,
    LIB_TRUE=1
};

typedef int lib_bool_t;
```

are mapped to Swift as

```
struct library_consts : RawRepresentable {
    init(_ rawValue: UInt32)
    init(rawValue: UInt32)
    var rawValue: UInt32
}

typealias lib_bool_t = Int32
```

(the C `int` type is `Int32` in Swift).

Swift does no implicit type conversions, which means that you have
to convert the types explicitly. In the second case it would be

```
var b: another_struct = another_struct()
b.aFlag = lib_bool_t(LIB_FALSE.rawValue)
```

Comment: This is disappointing, Swift feels like a big step backwards. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @clawoo: Well, that depends on how you look at it. Not converting types implicitly seems to be one of the major design decisions in Swift. It helps to avoid errors like the famous `char c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) ... ` which may never terminate if `char` is an unsigned type on your platform.